# Census Solidarity?

Tags: united-states, immigration

I have heard that immigrants are concerned about the census because it will contain a question along the lines of “Are you a citizen?” I have been wondering if there might be a way for me to show solidarity with them. Some ideas I had would be to just say “No,” or refuse to answer the question, or refuse to take the census.

I understand that civil disobedience has inherent risk, but I would prefer not to get myself in trouble if possible. Is there any safe way I can show solidarity?

Comment: The census for which country?

Comment: This sounds like a question for politics SE and not law.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about law.

Answer (score 2):

If you lie on the census you can receive a fine. 
https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/white-house/are-you-citizen-here-s-what-happens-if-you-lie-n861841

If you don't like the question, write your congressman.

Comment: So saying "No" would be lying. How about leaving the question blank?

Comment: You can't leave it blank. If you don't like the question you have to answer it truthfully, but you can voice your opinion on it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please clarify can't: Can't because it's illegal, can't because it will invalidate your census, can't because someone will knock on your door as if you had not sent in a census, can't because you just can't? I know some online things you can't leave black, but the census is still a mail in form (right?)

Comment: Well you can mail it in, but they have people go around and ask questions. You get a fine if they choose to persue it if you don't answer it all correctly.

Comment: The law says you must answer each question truthfully, if not you can be fined.

Comment: @Damila: Giving a false answer makes you liable to be fined under 13 USC 221(b). Refusing to answer a question makes you liable to be fined under 13 USC 221(a).

Comment: Liable to be fined, but I wonder how often it actually happens.  I never answer the race question on any form.  (On web forms that don't except a non-answer, I either check everything or don't complete the form.)